# Using tesseract without leptonica

Tags: visual-c++, tesseract

Is there possible to use tesseract without leptonica ? (to get rid of Leptonica problems, of course). If is possible, how ?

Comment: I have found here a possible answer :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230127/building-tesseract-without-leptonica?rq=1

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Comment: No, I am using tesseract with leptonica. And goes well.